# Why did they name it Super Friends rather than Justice League of America?

Tags: title, comic-adaptation, super-friends

The [*Super Friends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Friends) animated show was based on the famous DC comic book team *Justice League of America*, but they didn't name it that and made up a new team name instead. Why did they do that?

I thought that it was some rights issue but in the opening credits of [*Challenge of the Super Friends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge_of_the_Super_Friends) they called the team ***Justice League of America***. So why did they make a new name for the show rather than using the already existing popular name?

Comment: I have no proof of this, but probably because it was a kids show so they wanted to "dumb it down" a bit for kids. it's a show about a bunch of friends who have super powers -- Super Friends.

Comment: @KutuluMike sound plausable if it can be sourced

Comment: the only source I can find says that they definitely dumbed down the _violence_ for kids, but not why they changed the name. still looking.